# How to read UDT object into result query?

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql, user-defined-types, oracle-manageddataaccess

I have a User defined type with many attributes like so:

```
create or replace type MyObject is object
(
    attribute 1,
    attribute 2,
    attribute 3
    ...
)
```

I have a function that returns that object:

```
create or replace function GetMyObject
(...params...)
return MyObject
is
...
```

Now I attempt to call that function from a C# application using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`. Because `MyObject` is not known type to C#, I try to call `OracleCommand.ExecuteReader()` and read the values of attributes from a result query one by one:

```
select GetMyObject(...) from dual;
```

What I am getting in Oracle is this table:

```
    |    GetMyObject(...)   |
--------------------------------
 1  |  [UserName.MyObject]  |
```

Instead I expect to get this :

```
    | attribute 1 | attribute 2 | attribute 3 | ...
------------------------------------------------------
 1  |   value 1   |   value 2   |   value 3   | ...
```

How should the select statement look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of "objects" is that they are composite data, treated as single units. That is why you are seeing what you are seeing.

If you want to see the individual components, you will need to `SELECT` three columns (or however many), not one. And to access the individual attributes, one per column, you must use "dot" notation.

```
select GetMyObject(...).attribute1 as attribute1
     , GetMyObject(...).attribute2 as attribute2
--   (etc.)
from dual;
```

Obviously, I assume you didn't actually have spaces in attribute names.

Comment: Isn't there some unpacking function that will do that for me? I have many such calls in my application and going over all of them is pretty much a huge rewrite. I hoped for some abstraction at the select statement level.

Comment: @sanitizedUser - I don't understand your question. If you have a table that stores objects that have already been created, the syntax is much simpler (it's actually the simplest possible). I imagine you would use the function to create the objects so that you can then store them as already-created objects, in which case you wouldn't call the function in `select`. On the other hand, if you really need to call functions in SQL, why do you have functions that return one object, instead of separate functions returning their attributes?